# Find a specific element within a vector

Tags: vector, iterator, find

I have a class team that contains information for football teams. I need to read in a file and add each unique team to a vector season.

//Loop to determine unique teams

```
    if(season.size() <= 1)
        {
            season.push_back(new_team);
            cout << "First team added!" << endl;
        }

    vector<team>::iterator point;
    point = find(season.begin(), season.end(), new_team);
    bool unique_team = (point != season.end());
    if(unique_team == true && season.size()>1)
        {
            season.push_back(new_team);
            cout << "New team added!" << endl;
        }

    cout << "# of Teams: " << season.size() << endl;
    system("pause");
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work? I'm still new to this :-) So feel free to give constructive criticism.

Comment: I think your logic may be a little off, shouldn't the first team be added when the size of the season vector is 0. If the first team has been added you don't need to check if it is in the vector to add it again. Your find(...) code works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your logic may be a little off. There first team should be added when the size of the teams vector is 0. Say your team is a vector of integers an insertTeam function would look something like this.

```
void Season::insertTeam(int team)
{
    if (teams.size() == 0)
    {
        teams.push_back(team);
        cout << "First team " << team << " added!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        vector<int>::iterator point;
        point = find(teams.begin(), teams.end(), team);
        bool unique_team = (point == teams.end());
        if(unique_team == true && teams.size()>0)
        {
            teams.push_back(team);
            cout << "New team " << team << " added!" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```